# Given 2 points in 3d, how to generate a plane equation in the form $lx+my+nz=d$

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

I can do this for 2d points by getting the 2 parametric equations for $x$ and $y$ and then solving by eliminating $t$ and getting the 2d equivilent line equation. There is only one line equation in this case though.

In 3d there will be infinitely many planes but I only need one of them for my use case. I can still generate the symmetric line by doing the below

\begin{align*}x & = {x_0} + ta\\ y & = {y_0} + tb\\  z & = {z_0} + tc\end{align*}

which rearranges to

\begin{align*}\frac{{x - {x_0}}}{a} = \frac{{y - {y_0}}}{b} = \frac{{z - {z_0}}}{c}\end{align*}

What I want to do is get one of the planes that does go through the 2 points in  the form

\begin{align*}lx+my+nz = d\end{align*}

The reason for doing this is to solve a plane / Bezier curve intersection (which I have working in 2d)

Example given the following cubic

\begin{align*}\mathbf{X}(t) = (1-t)^3\mathbf{P}_0 + 3t(1-t)^2\mathbf{P}_1 + 
               3t^2(1-t)\mathbf{P}_2 + t^3\mathbf{P}_3\end{align*}

And the following line vector equation

\begin{align*}\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{X} = d\end{align*}

with \begin{align*}\mathbf{A} = (l,m,n)\end{align*}

I just need to solve

\begin{align*}(1-t)^3(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{P}_0) + 
3t(1-t)^2(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{P}_1) + 
3t^2(1-t)(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{P}_2) + 
t^3(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{P}_3) - d = 0\end{align*}

to be able to get the intersection points.

So how do I generate a example plane equation that does go through these 2 points?

**Update :**

I realise with 2 points there are infinitely many planes, I have rephrased the question to ask how to generate one of them or the formula for generating all of them.

Comment: Maybe my question was wrong or not asked correct, to perform 3d line intersection with a 3d bezier curve I need to find a plane coincident with the 3D line segment. That plane being in the form above.

Comment: Two points define a line, not a plane. There are infinitely many possible planes that contain the two points (and the line through them). That single equation that you are looking for defines a plane, so cannot be uniquely determined. You'd need 3 points to uniquely define a plane and get such an equation.

Comment: Please see my last comment, I think I just need a plane that is coincident with the 3D line segment.

Comment: But what are you then calculating? The $X(t)$ defines some curved line, a Bezier curve. You have two other points in space somewhere, and the line through them likely does not itself intersect your Bezier curve. You can get a plane through the two points and any third point that lies on your Bezier curve. So depending on which plane you choose, you can get it to intersect your Bezier curve anywhere you like.

Comment: One solution ignores the second equation, and the olane's equation is $(x-x_0)/a=(y-y_0)/b$

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - What you say is true but I am only interested in solutions of the parametric equations where t is between 0 and 1 so the other intersections will be ignored when they are outside this range.

Comment: But that still means that you can get the plane to intersect at any point $X(t)$ with $0\le t \le 1$. Just pick a $t$ in that range, calculate the point $X(t)$ and set up the equation for a plane through three points $X(t)$, $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $(x_0+a,y_0+b,z_0+c)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{{x - {x_0}}}{a} = \frac{{y - {y_0}}}{b} = \frac{{z - {z_0}}}{c}$$
means
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{{x - {x_0}}}{a} = \frac{{y - {y_0}}}{b}\\
\frac{{y - {y_0}}}{b} = \frac{{z - {z_0}}}{c}\\
\end{cases}
$$
The line is given as intersection of two planes. Any linear combinations of the two planes gives a plane passing through the two given points.
$$
\begin{cases}
b(x - {x_0}) - a(y - {y_0})=0\to bx-ay+h=0\\
c(y - {y_0}) - b(z - {z_0})=0\to cy-bz+k=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$\alpha:\lambda(bx-ay+h)+\mu(cy-bz+k)=0$$

---

Easier alternative

Suppose we have two points $P=(1,2,3);\;Q=(2,1,1)$

Vector joining the two points is $\vec{QP}=(1,-1,-2)$

A vector $\vec{n}=(a,b,c)$ is normal to $\vec{QP}$ is $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{QP}=0$, that is

$a-b-2c=0\to b=a-2c$

$\vec{n}=(a,a-2c,c)$

The equation of the plane passing through $P$ and normal to $\vec{n}$ is

$$a(x-x_P)+b(y-y_P)+c(z-z_P)=0$$

$$a(x-1)+(a-2c)(y-2)+c(z-3)=0\to a x+(a -2 c) y+c z+c-3a=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose given $\dfrac{{x_1 - {x_0}}}{a} = \dfrac{{y_1 - {y_0}}}{b} = \dfrac{{z_1 - {z_0}}}{c}$. Where $x_1 ,y_1 ,z_1$ is any point on the line and $x_0 ,y_0 ,z_0$ is the fixed point on the line.
Imagine another line going through the same fixed point $x_0 ,y_0 ,z_0$. We write this equation as $\dfrac{{x_2 - {x_0}}}{a_1} = \dfrac{{y_2 - {y_0}}}{b_1} = \dfrac{{z_2 - {z_0}}}{c_1}$
Now we consider any line which lies on the plane created by this two line. Consider a point $x,y,z$ on this plane so 
$x-x_0 = \alpha(x_1 - {x_0})+\beta(x_2-x_0) = \alpha at+\beta a_1k\\
y-y_0 = \alpha(y_1 - {y_0})+\beta(y_2-y_0) = \alpha bt+\beta b_1k\\
z-z_0 = \alpha(z_1 - {z_0})+\beta(z_2-z_0) = \alpha ct+\beta c_1k\
$

Solve for $\alpha t$ and $\beta k$ from first two equations and replace those in third equation.